# a python program that gets a number from a user and sums its characters except for two particular number

Tags: python, string, exception, sum

for example, the given number is 4211256: I want to  sum all the digits without adding 11; the result of the given number addition will be: 19

I wrote the first part of the program code but I couldn't continue it

```
n=int(input("Enter number: "))

sum=0

for digit in str(n):
    sum=sum+int(digit)
    while 11:
    pass
print("Sum of digits",sum)
```

Comment: `while 11` is always True.

Comment: What about 42111256? What's the expected output? 19 or 20?

Comment: it will be 20. I just want to remove 11. if there are 111 I want to remove 11 and a 1 still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n = input("Enter number: ")
result = sum(map(int, list(n.replace('11', ''))))
```

You get rid of '11' by replacing '11' with '' (there's no need to convert n to an integer and then back to a string), and then you sum the remaining digits.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option and calculate the sums in parts:

```py
def get_sum_without_11(s):
    s_without11 = s.split("11")
    return sum([getSum(n) for n in s_without11])

def get_sum(n):
    sum = 0
    for digit in str(n): 
      sum += int(digit)      
    return sum
    
n=int(input("Enter number: "))

print(get_sum_without_11(s))
```